# Pandas: Sort groups of rows instead of individual rows

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I'm trying to find a way to sort data based on column pairs.  My current code below gets very close, but I would finally want to move Joe to the top - **and keep all of his rows together** - since his total is greatest.

**Update 1:** `'Total'` will not always be the maximum - so it needs to use the `'Yes'` designation - (some of the dollar amounts could be negative).

**Update 2:** My code and desired outputs have been updated to show where a `'Total'` row may be less than another `'Dollar'` in the group (due to negative dollars), but it should still be the first row of that `'Dude'` group.

My code gets the grouping correct, but doesn't ultimately sort the `'Dude'` groups.

```
import pandas as pd

headers = ['Date','Dude','Dollar', 'Total']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dude':['Bob','Bob','Sam','Bob','Joe','Joe','Joe','Bob','Sam','Sam','Joe','Sam'], 
    'Dollar':[4,1,-2,1,5,12,3,2,7,1,4,8],
    'Total':['Yes','No','No','No','No','Yes','No','No','Yes','No','No','No'],
    'Date':['1/1/2016','1/1/2016','1/1/2016','3/1/2016','3/1/2016','1/1/2016','1/1/2016','5/1/2016','1/1/2016','3/1/2016','5/1/2016','5/1/2016']
    }, columns = headers)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df.sort_values(by = ['Dude','Total','Date'], ascending = [True, False, True], inplace = True)
```

Output:

```
         Date Dude  Dollar Total
0  2016-01-01  Bob       4   Yes
1  2016-01-01  Bob       1    No
3  2016-03-01  Bob       1    No
7  2016-05-01  Bob       2    No
5  2016-01-01  Joe      12   Yes
6  2016-01-01  Joe       3    No
4  2016-03-01  Joe       5    No
10 2016-05-01  Joe       4    No
8  2016-01-01  Sam       7   Yes
2  2016-01-01  Sam      -2    No
9  2016-03-01  Sam       1    No
11 2016-05-01  Sam       8    No
```

Desired output:

```
         Date Dude  Dollar Total
5  2016-01-01  Joe      12   Yes
6  2016-01-01  Joe       3    No
4  2016-03-01  Joe       5    No
10 2016-05-01  Joe       4    No
8  2016-01-01  Sam       7   Yes
2  2016-01-01  Sam      -2    No
9  2016-03-01  Sam       1    No
11 2016-05-01  Sam       8    No
0  2016-01-01  Bob       4   Yes
1  2016-01-01  Bob       1    No
3  2016-03-01  Bob       1    No
7  2016-05-01  Bob       2    No
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution ... it first finds all the "Yes" rows, merges those back into the original dataframe, and then sorts first on those.

```
import pandas as pd

headers = ['Date','Dude','Dollar', 'Total']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dude':['Bob','Bob','Sam','Bob','Joe','Joe','Joe','Bob','Sam','Sam','Joe','Sam'], 
    'Dollar':[4,1,-2,1,5,12,3,2,7,1,4,8],
    'Total':['Yes','No','No','No','No','Yes','No','No','Yes','No','No','No'],
    'Date':['1/1/2016','1/1/2016','1/1/2016','3/1/2016','3/1/2016','1/1/2016','1/1/2016','5/1/2016','1/1/2016','3/1/2016','5/1/2016','5/1/2016']
    }, columns = headers)

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Just the Total = Yes row for each dude, with dollar renamed to total_dollar
totals = df.loc[df['Total'] == 'Yes', ['Dude', 'Dollar']]
totals.columns = ['Dude', 'Total_Dollar']

# Merge back on dude, sort by total dollars before sorting by everything else 
df = df.merge(totals, on='Dude').sort_values(by = ['Total_Dollar', 'Dude', 'Total', 'Date'], ascending = [False, True, False, True])
del df['Total_Dollar']
```

Output:

```
         Date Dude  Dollar Total
9  2016-01-01  Joe      12   Yes
10 2016-01-01  Joe       3    No
8  2016-03-01  Joe       5    No
11 2016-05-01  Joe       4    No
5  2016-01-01  Sam       7   Yes
4  2016-01-01  Sam      -2    No
6  2016-03-01  Sam       1    No
7  2016-05-01  Sam       8    No
0  2016-01-01  Bob       4   Yes
1  2016-01-01  Bob       1    No
2  2016-03-01  Bob       1    No
3  2016-05-01  Bob       2    No
```

Comment: Hi Igor - thanks, but I don't want to change any of the data, simply sort it.

Comment: Ok changed it back to the original data ... just changed the example for illustrative purposes. Or is it the merging thats bad?

Comment: I like your idea to use `merge` +1. A bit shorter version: `df.merge(totals).sort_values(['Total_Dollar', 'Dude', 'Total', 'Date'], ascending = [0, 1, 0, 1]).drop('Total_Dollar',1)`

Comment: Great solution, thank you Igor! And everyone else. Keeping the 'Dude' in there was actually necessary - forget what I said before.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the 'Dude' column as a categorical data type with your desired ordering, then sort as you did before.  This would also give you the other benefits of having the 'Dude' column as categorical.

```
# Get the ordering of Dudes based on max dollar.
dude_order = df[df['Total'] == 'Yes'].sort_values(by='Dollar', ascending=False)

# Set dude as categorical with the previously determined ordering.
df['Dude'] = df['Dude'].astype('category', categories=dude_order['Dude'], ordered=True)

# Sort the dataframe.
df = df.sort_values(by=['Dude', 'Total', 'Date'], ascending=[True, False, True])
```

The resulting output:

```
         Date Dude  Dollar Total
5  2016-01-01  Joe      12   Yes
6  2016-01-01  Joe       3    No
4  2016-03-01  Joe       5    No
10 2016-05-01  Joe       4    No
8  2016-01-01  Sam       7   Yes
2  2016-01-01  Sam      -2    No
9  2016-03-01  Sam       1    No
11 2016-05-01  Sam       8    No
0  2016-01-01  Bob       4   Yes
1  2016-01-01  Bob       1    No
3  2016-03-01  Bob       1    No
7  2016-05-01  Bob       2    No
```

Comment: this is smart !

Comment: last two +1s... I feel naked

Comment: I should have added one other caveat - `'Total'` will not always be the maximum - so it needs to use the `'Yes'` designation.

Comment: @pshep123: I'm not sure I follow what you mean by that?  Can you add more example rows (or alter the existing rows) to reflect the new requirement?

Comment: Updated to reflect a `'Total'` row being less than a non-`'Total'` row.

Comment: @pshep123: Will there only be one 'Yes' designation per 'Dude', or could there potentially be multiple?

Comment: Good question - only one 'Yes' per 'Dude'.

Comment: @pshep123:  Updated my answer.  The process is generally the same, I just altered the process to get the 'Dude' order, which resulted in a minor change in how it's supplied to the `astype` (passed as a column instead of an index).

Comment: Great, thanks @root.  Just accepted Igor's answer as it got me what I needed as well.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [162]: m = df.loc[df.Total=='Yes'].set_index('Dude')['Dollar']

In [163]: m
Out[163]:
Dude
Bob     4
Joe    12
Sam     7
Name: Dollar, dtype: int64

In [164]: df.assign(x=df.Dude.map(m)) \
     ...:   .sort_values(['x','Dude','Total','Date'], ascending=[0,1,0,1]) \
     ...:   .drop('x', 1)
Out[164]:
         Date Dude  Dollar Total
5  2016-01-01  Joe      12   Yes
6  2016-01-01  Joe       3    No
4  2016-03-01  Joe       5    No
10 2016-05-01  Joe       4    No
8  2016-01-01  Sam       7   Yes
2  2016-01-01  Sam      -2    No
9  2016-03-01  Sam       1    No
11 2016-05-01  Sam       8    No
0  2016-01-01  Bob       4   Yes
1  2016-01-01  Bob       1    No
3  2016-03-01  Bob       1    No
7  2016-05-01  Bob       2    No
```

**Old answer:**

```
In [96]: df.assign(x=df.groupby('Dude').Dollar.transform('max')) \
    ...:   .sort_values(['x','Dude','Dollar','Date'], ascending=[0,1,0,1]) \
    ...:   .drop('x',1)
Out[96]:
         Date Dude  Dollar Total
5  2016-01-01  Joe      12   Yes
4  2016-03-01  Joe       5    No
10 2016-05-01  Joe       4    No
6  2016-01-01  Joe       3    No
8  2016-01-01  Sam       8   Yes
11 2016-05-01  Sam       5    No
2  2016-01-01  Sam       2    No
9  2016-03-01  Sam       1    No
0  2016-01-01  Bob       4   Yes
7  2016-05-01  Bob       2    No
1  2016-01-01  Bob       1    No
3  2016-03-01  Bob       1    No
```

Comment: @pshep123, what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, that was a joke.  You're always quick on the draw - it is much appreciated!  But I'm not joking about trying to digest it.  Just going through it step by step.

Comment: I should have added one other caveat - `'Total'` will not always be the maximum - so it needs to use the `'Yes'` designation.

Comment: @pshep123, that's getting challenging - i like it ;)

Comment: want to keep your game sharp!